# Ansible 'no_log' for specific values in debug output, not entire module

Tags: automation, ansible, yaml, redhat, vmware

I am studying for the RedHat Certified Specialist in Ansible Automation (EX407) and I'm playing around with the `no_log` module parameter. I have a sample playbook structured as so;

```
---
- hosts: webservers
  tasks:
  - name: Query vCenter
    vmware_guest:
      hostname: "{{ vcenter['host'] }}"
      username: "{{ vcenter['username'] }}"
      password: "{{ vcenter['password'] }}"
      name: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      validate_certs: no
    delegate_to: localhost
    no_log: yes
...
```

When `no_log` is disabled, I get a lot of helpful debug information about my VM, but when `no_log` is disabled I obviously can't protect my playbooks vaulted data (in this case that is the `vcenter['username']` and `vcenter['password']` values). Enabling `no_log` cripples my playbooks debug output to just;

```
"censored": "the output has been hidden due to the fact that 'no_log: true' was specified for this result",
```

I would like to know how it is possible to censor only some of the debug output. I know this is possible because `vcenter['password']` is protected in it's output regardless of my `no_log` state. I see this in the verbose output when `no_log` is disabled;

```
"invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "username": "administrator@vsphere.local"
        }
}
```

What are your thoughts?

Comment: Unfortunately this is a bad design on ansible part, to not allow to hide the inputs, especially in loops, unless you hide everything, that might be even worse. There was an issue to hide the module parameters from the output (https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/69373), but they closed it as "by design". In that case it's understandable, but not for loops, whose outputted items can be handled and hidden by ansible (https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/38214). Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/1059530

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I went digging through the VMWare module source code and [this](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.vmware/blob/f57e815666744a9369be32e6702fbc69c4e58027/plugins/module_utils/vmware.py#L526) is what I found.

```
password=dict(type='str',
              aliases=['pass', 'pwd'],
              required=False,
              no_log=True,
              fallback=(env_fallback, ['VMWARE_PASSWORD'])),
```

Looks like Playbooks just aren't exposing this feature. The VMWare modules themselves are enabling `no_log` on specific attributes in Python. For my part, this is just another functionality Playbooks are hiding. I really wish it was standard to suppress specific attributes, rather than a whole module, but this is where it stands as of Ansible 2.10.

Comment: Yeah, if there was a way to set a specific variable in Ansible to no_log that'd be handy. Like `vars.var1.value` and `vars.var1.no_log=true` I'd be happy.

Comment: This isn't fixing the problem of data spill when using the module in a loop. You would still have to adjust `loop_control.label` to hide the sensitive data from the default output